# The set consists of all points in a given circle is an algebraic set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $D=\left\{{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\leq a^2}\right\}$ where $x, y\in \mathbb R$.

Is it true that $D$ is an algebraic set ?

I guess that's maybe a silly question but I can't prove or disprove it.

Comment: The crucial question to ask is whether the set of polynomials for the algebraic set has to be finite.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an algebraic set?

Comment: D  is a infinite union of algebraic sets in form $x^2+y^2= b^2$, $b\leq a$. But I can't go any further from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $U\neq \mathbb{R}$ whose interior is non-empty (for the topology induced by the euclidean metric) can never be an algebraic set. Polynomials that vanish on an open set, are constantly zero. If you assume $U$ to be an algebraic set, then by definition it would be the set of common zeros of some set of polynomials, but then all these polynomials must be constantly zero and it must be $U=V(\{0\})=\mathbb{R}^n$, contradicting our assumption.

Your example of the open disk is a special case of this. As long as $a\neq 0$, $D$ is subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with $D\neq\mathbb{R}^2$) that has a non-empty interior, so it cannot be an algebraic set.

Comment: Hello. I still don't see why Polynomials that vanish on an open set, are constantly zero ? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm is it clear to you that a polynomial $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that vanishes on an open set is constant?

Comment: of course, it is since f has only finitely  roots. But a polynomial in two variables may admits infinitely  roots ?

Comment: Yes, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ either has finitely many roots or is constantly zero. Now if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ vanishes on an open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, take any $x\in U$ and consider the lines in $\mathbb{R}^n$ through $x$. What do you know about the restrictions of $f$ to those lines?

Comment: Thank you  I understand it now.

Comment: btw, $D$ is a closed set in $R^2$.  Your arguments still be valid since if $f$ vanishes  on an closed set then it also vanishes on its interior.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant^^ The crucial point is that $D$ has a non-empty interior, so the polynomials that vanish on $D$ vanish on some open set.

Comment: I come up with a proof that's similar to your idea.  Fix $x \in R$ and view $f\neq 0$ as a polynomial in $K[y]$ so there are finitely roots $y$.  This is contraction since in the disk there are infinitely points in form $(x,a)$

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right, but it is possible that $f$ is constantly zero along some line in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but not constantly zero on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for instance consider $f(x,y)=x$, this is constantly zero on the line $\{(0,y)|y\in\mathbb{R}\}$)